# Reading test cases from a file

Tags: c, file, io

I was asked to solve a programming challenge, and there is this line which I don't understand can some one explain to me how can I pass the test cases to the program using this command, I think I have to store it in some file but I am not sure

```
size_t getline(char **lineptr,size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

here is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
size_t getline(char **lineptr,size_t *n, FILE *stream);
int main()
{ 
    size_t maxLineLen=1024;
    char *line = (char*)malloc(maxLineLen);
    while(getline(&line, &maxLineLen,stdin)!= -1){
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
        printf("%s\n",line);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [getline man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline). If you still have questions after reading that then please clarify exactly what it is you do not understand from there.

Comment: Did you read `man getline`?

Comment: @kaylum I went through and it dinot explain how to pass the test cases

Comment: If you don't even understand what the program should do, how could we possibly know? You need to understand what your program is expected to do before you write a single line of code.

Comment: Note that the POSIX specification of [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) specifies a return type of `ssize_t` — rather than `size_t` (which is just as well since it returns `-1` when it detects EOF).

Comment: Well I know what it do, But in the platform of the challenge the code was just like that and the test cases provided using GUI in the right side (like codility but not codility I am keeping it confidential in case it was illegal ) was passed to the program, I am wondering if I want to run it in my normal compiler is this correct and enough ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are asking how to run the given code and get input into.

```
getline(&line, &maxLineLen,stdin)
```

That reads a line from `stdin`. `stdin` is a standard file stream and is opened by the startup code for you. Without redirection, reading from `stdin` will get the input typed into the terminal

So to get input into the program you can do one of the following:

1. Run the program and then type each input line into the terminal.
2. Run the program and then redirect a file into the program. Example:

   `./my_program < my_input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Are you given a file name?

Then the FILE * parameter would have to be opened via fopen.

See [manual for fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)

Comment: yes that is why I am surprised that it was working with only the code I provided in the platform of the question

Comment: As per the other comment, they might have said reading from a file was actually passed in via stdin. So using scanf() would have been ok to read that "file" that was redirection in.

Comment: The code shows that it is using `stdin`; that is supposed to be open when the program is started.  It is not clear that this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Title of the question was "Reading test cases from a file". So yes, stdin is a FILE *, but it seemed like OP wished to read from a file, not stdin. There was also no indication that the inputfile was redirected in.